# How to access this JSON object - not defined error

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var output = "<div>";
     $.getJSON('https://search-a.akamaihd.net/typeahead/suggest/?solrformat=true&rows=20&callback=noCB&q=*%3A*+AND+schoolid_s%3A1255&defType=edismax&qf=teacherfirstname_t%5E2000+teacherlastname_t%5E2000+teacherfullname_t%5E2000+autosuggest&bf=pow(total_number_of_ratings_i%2C2.1)&sort=total_number_of_ratings_i+desc&siteName=rmp&rows=20&start=0&fl=pk_id+teacherfirstname_t+teacherlastname_t+total_number_of_ratings_i+averageratingscore_rf+schoolid_s&fq=&prefix=schoolname_t%3A%22University+of+Texas+at+Austin%22&callback=?' , function(data) {

        for (var professor in data.noCB.response.docs) {  //where the error might be
           output += "a"
        }
       output += "</div>"
   });
   document.getElementById("listt").innerHTML = output;
});
```

This is the url that I call to get the JSON data :

This is the url with the data :

[JSON Data](https://search-a.akamaihd.net/typeahead/suggest/?solrformat=true&rows=20&callback=noCB&q=*%3A*%20AND%20schoolid_s%3A1255&defType=edismax&qf=teacherfirstname_t%5E2000%20teacherlastname_t%5E2000%20teacherfullname_t%5E2000%20autosuggest&bf=pow(total_number_of_ratings_i%2C2.1)&sort=total_number_of_ratings_i%20desc&siteName=rmp&rows=20&start=0&fl=pk_id%20teacherfirstname_t%20teacherlastname_t%20total_number_of_ratings_i%20averageratingscore_rf%20schoolid_s&fq=&prefix=schoolname_t%3A%22University%20of%20Texas%20at%20Austin%22)

I get the error - noCB is not defined .

I guess I'm trying to access the JSON object the wrong way - but I'm unsure about the right way. Please let me know - I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you're getting is using JSONP (not JSON). Instead of `data.noCB.response.docs`, you'd just use `data.response.docs`. `noCB` isn't part of the object, it's a function call (that's how JSONP works).

You also want to remove `callback=noCB` from the URL, so that jQuery will handle the JSONP plumbing for you.

You have a couple of other issues as well:

1. You're trying to use `output` before you've filled it in. See [*How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for details.
2. Don't use `for-in` to loop through arrays unless you do it advisedly with safeguards; see [*For-each over an array in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) for details.

Finally, not an *issue* per se, but as long as you're using jQuery, you may as well use it for things like `document.getElementById("listt").innerHTML = output;` (e.g.: `$("#listt").html(output);`).

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var output = "<div>";
  $.getJSON('https://search-a.akamaihd.net/typeahead/suggest/?solrformat=true&rows=20&q=*%3A*+AND+schoolid_s%3A1255&defType=edismax&qf=teacherfirstname_t%5E2000+teacherlastname_t%5E2000+teacherfullname_t%5E2000+autosuggest&bf=pow(total_number_of_ratings_i%2C2.1)&sort=total_number_of_ratings_i+desc&siteName=rmp&rows=20&start=0&fl=pk_id+teacherfirstname_t+teacherlastname_t+total_number_of_ratings_i+averageratingscore_rf+schoolid_s&fq=&prefix=schoolname_t%3A%22University+of+Texas+at+Austin%22&callback=?', function(data) {
    data.response.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
      output += "a";
    });
    output += "</div>";
    document.getElementById("listt").innerHTML = output;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="listt"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```